# What is the difference between "wie" and "was" in a certain context?

Tags: grammar, difference

When do you use *wie* and *was* in German?

For example:

> What is your name?

I understand you ask the question with *wie* instead of *was*.

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you going.

Comment: @TomAu: You don't need upvotes to get going. You're misusing the voting system. Are you buying friends?

Comment: @userunknown: For people of less than 100 "earned" reputation, I will up vote a "pretty good," rather than "very good" answer. The most vulnerable period for new people is when they join the site. People need to get "quick" upvotes so they come back to the site. Once they're more or less established, then stricter standards apply. But this upvote for newbies means, "You're on the right track, I'm keeping an eye on you."

Comment: @TomAu: That is your personal opinion. I don't think people are vulnerable. Nor do I believe in immunization by votes. Ich halte das im Gegenteil für eine durch und durch korrupte Denkweise.

Comment: @userunknown Inwiefern ist das jetzt *nicht* Deine persönliche Meinung?

Comment: @Jan: [Diskussion gerne auf Meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/393/266)

Comment: This question does not make sense without stating which German expression is intended for “is your name”.

Comment: Related (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23199/sagt-man-was-ist-ihr-name

Comment: very good on the upvote. yes, there are many sharks circling dying to impress nervous newcomers with the fact that there's no such thing as DO and IDO in German thus setting them back weeks.

Answer (score 25):

**Wie** means *how*, and **was** means *what*.

But the confusion arises from the fact that the same idea is rendered differently in English than in German.

In English, we say, "What is your name?". The literal German translation is "**Was ist dein Name?**".

But in German, we say, "**Wie heißen Sie?**" or "**Wie heißt du?**" (respectively, formal and informal). And the literal English translation is "How are you called?"

Other expressions also have different renderings. "Ich habe Hunger" literally translates into "I HAVE hunger", but the English equivalent is "I AM hungry".

Comment: Regarding *I am hungry*. We do say the literal translation in German: *Ich bin hungrig.* In English you can say *I feel hungry* what is not possible in German.

Comment: But +1 for the second sentence. I think THIS is the most important point. German and English language handles it different. It's something what you've to learn, get the feeling for it. It's not a part of speech for what a rule exists for.

Comment: As a apart to my previous comment. There are a lot of examples the use of which is different. Example: *Wofür ist das? - What is that for?* - (Literally (bad) translation: Where is it for - Was ist das für).

Comment: actually the literal translation for "How are you called?" is "Wie werden sie genannt?" and not "Wie heißen sie."... it is nit picking though :)

Also the question "Wie ist Ihr Name?" is common. The actual confusion is there. Why is it "wie" and not "was"... I think some people might also say "was"

Comment: @Em1 An even worse translation I regret to here often is "Für was ist das?". I fear we loose a lot of the German constructs that makes the language what it is, altough I know that it eveolves permanently.

Comment: @harper: That's a *better* translation, isn't it? I mean, translating "wofür" as "where for" is simply semantically wrong. "Für was", in contrast, might not be good style, or it might even be considered wrong if one interprets substitution rules like "für was -> wofür" very narrowly, but it unquestionably conveys the correct idea: asking about (the purpose of) a thing ("was") rather than for a location ("where").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper There is no location in "wofür". https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wofuer

Comment: @harper: Exactly. But there seems to be in the (overly) literal translation "where for" that you commented on.

Answer (score 6):

"Wie" means *how* and "was" means *what*. In general, you can translate them that way, but as you noticed, there are some special cases that you learn best by comming across them and looking them up.

Translating "what is your name" would literally result in "was ist dein Name". This actually is a valid sentence/question!

"Wie heißt du" might be a bit more common, but "wie" makes sense here. *How* something "heißt", makes the something valid: if "A heißt B", A *is called* B. Now you can also ask *what* A "heißt": "was heißt A", which translates to *what does A **mean***.

Comment: So "Du heißt was?"?

Answer (score 3):

-- "When do you use "wie" and "was" in German?" --

In general we use those words similar to English. We ask *wie* when we want to know *how* something is and we ask *was* if we want to know *what* something is.

For some abstract things the two languages handle it different if you ask with *wie/how* or *was/what* and sometimes they're equal. In many cases both languages support phrases for the same thing with both words (with sometimes a subtle different meaning):

> Woran denkst du? - Where is your mind? (*)
>
> Was denkst du? - What do you think?

<sub>(*)Note: If you ask *What's on your mind* it expresses - imho - that something weighs someone down while *Where is your mind* does not.</sub>

In case of *name* English is different to German, but note that in other languages may also be different ways to ask. In Russian they ask with *как(how)*, in French with *comment(how)* or *quel(which/what)* and in Spain and Italian I think it's similar to French.

B2T - In German we usually ask:

> Wie heisst du?

But those are also possible (but are less in use):

> Wie ist dein Name?
>
> Welchen Namen hast du?
>
> Wie lautet dein Name?

And if you ask *Was ist dein Name?* I think that's absolutely OK, because it has almost as many hits on google as *Wie ist dein Name?* but, though, I would never say that.

Summarized: In case of *name* it's much more usual to take *wie* or *welchen* rather than *was*, but in general (and that was your first question) it's not possible to give a clear answer. For every abstract thing the way how you ask can be different and there is no rule (and also no rule of thumb). It's something which is developed with time. Fortunately, it's often the same word.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two mainly has to do with the verb being used or the action taking place. To ask for someone's name in German, you are really asking "how" they are called or how their name is called, not "what" their name is like in English. Look for what verb is being used or implied to help determine which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with

> Wie ist dein Name?

is, that funny people could just answer:

> Lang!

or something, because in a strict sense the "Wie" asks for properties of things (among others). (Of course, you could argue that the name of the name of Frau Schmidt is "Schmidt", but "Wie ist der Name deines Namens?" is, of course, almost impossible.)

I therefore recommend, to use "Was" or simply

> Wie heißt du?

Answer (score 0):

Wie ist dein Name originated from the German habit of dubbing non-German movies and has migrated into German TV. Don't use it.

Comment: Easily disproved via Google Ngram Viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wie+ist+dein+Name&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3 The phrase is much older than television.

Comment: @chirlu True, it existed before, but it still sounds Denglish to me.