# Sagt man "Was ist Ihr Name"?

Tags: idiomaticity, interrogative

Normalerweise sagt man auf Deutsch

> Wie ist Ihr Name?

aber ich habe überlegt, ob

> Was ist Ihr Name?

auch möglich ist. Ist es das?

Comment: Nicht möglich. Obwohl man es verstehen würde, ist "was" hier fehl am Platz. Es ist wie mit falschen Präpositionen: Man versteht es, aber es ist falsch (z.B. "Ich fahre zu Berlin." <= falsch).

Comment: @äüö: Gibt es also für Name keinen Nominativ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normalerweise fragt man:

> Wie heißen Sie?

*Wie/was ist ihr Name?* hat für mich einen leicht denglishen Beigeschmack …

Comment: Ich habe "Wie ist Ihr Name?" im Buch http://www.schubert-verlag.de/begegnungen_a1.php Kapitel 1 gefunden.

Comment: Die einzige Situation in der ich mir vorstellen kann, die Frage "Wie ist Ihr Name?" zu benutzen ist, wenn es um einen Eintrag in ein Register geht - d.h. wenn der Name aufgeschrieben wird. Zum Beispiel wenn man sich im Hotel an der Rezeption anmeldet. Ich würde die Frage auch sonst nicht als grob falsch ansehen, udn vielleicht hat sie sich inzwischen auch ein bisschen mehr eingebürgert - aber trotzdem ist es ein bisschen unpersönlich.

Answer (score 6):

Es ist möglich, aber eher unüblich.

Answer (score 3):

Korrekt wäre, wenn beispielsweise zum Ausfüllen eines Formulars oder dergleichen danach gefragt wird:

> Wie lautet Ihr Name

Demgegenüber klingt

> Was ist Ihr Name

in meinen Augen nach falschem Deutsch.

> Wie ist Ihr Name

klingt in meinen Ohren zumindest etwas vereinfacht, eventuell mit einem etwas groben Unterton.

> Sagen Sie mir (noch) Ihren Namen (bitte)?

wäre beispielsweise am Telefon angemessen, ebenso

> Darf ich (nochmals) nach Ihrem namen fragen?

Comment: Wenn es in den Augen klingt, geht man dann eigentlich zum Augen- oder zum Ohrenarzt?

Answer (score 3):

Beide Versionen sind möglich, und beide Versionen klingen nach einer schlechten (weil zu wörtlichen) Übersetzung aus dem Englischen. Die bessere Version lautet:

> Wie heißen Sie?

Die deutsche Sprache enthält nämlich ein Verb, dass der englischen Sprache fehlt:

> heißen

Dieses Verb hat keine englische Entsprechung. Es wird wie folgt verwendet:

> <*Person/Tier/Ding*><sub>*(Nominativ)*</sub> <*Form von »heißen«*> <*Name*><sub>*(Nominativ)*</sub>.
>
> Ich heiße Hubert.
>   Gerds Mutter heißt Anna.
>   Dieser Hund heißt Rex.
>   Der Planet auf dem ich lebe heißt Erde.