# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "wie" und "was"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Ich weiß, dass *was* auf Englisch *what* und *wie* *how* bedeutet.

Aber manchmal kommt *wie* mit der Bedeutung *what* vor.

So wie hier:

> Wie ist deine Telefonnummer?

Geht es so auch?

> Was ist deine Telefonnummer?

Comment: Frage am Rande: Warum machst du in deinen Fragen immer Klammern um deutsche Worte? Auch deutsche Worte können kursiv oder unter Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden. Und `:-` ist im Deutschen auch nicht üblich.

Comment: Denn ich habe keine Anführungszeichen in meiner Tastatur wie du schon verwendet hast.
Sowieso danke sehr ^^

Comment: Außerdem bin ich Anfänger ^^ aber ich werde das nächste mal die Anführungszeichen  kopieren und dann einfügen um die deutsche Worte

Comment: The sentence “kommt mit der Bedeutung vor” ... means simply in English “comes with the meaning of” ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "wie" and "was" in a certain context?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/what-is-the-difference-between-wie-and-was-in-a-certain-context)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Annahme, dass "*wie*" in dem Beispielsatz mit der Bedeutung von "*what*" kommt, ist falsch. Genauso kann man sagen, dass "*what*" im Satz "*What is your phone number?*" mit der Bedeutung von "*wie*" (Deutsch für "*how*") kommt. Die deutsche und die englische Fragen sind auf unterschiedliche Weisen gebildet und man kann nicht einfach ein englisches Wort mit einem deutschen verknüpfen und dann fragen "*Warum bedeutet X hier Y, obwohl es normalerweise Z bedeutet*".

Die "richtige" Frage nach der Telefonnummer ist "*Wie **lautet** deine Telefonnumer?*". Also - "*wie*". Deshalb wird sie als "*Wie ist deine Telefonnumer?*" verkürzt.

Die Frage "Was ist deine Telefonnummer?" würde man auch verstehen. <strike>Genaugenommen bedeutet sie aber, dass man nicht weiß, was eine Telefonnummer ist (eine Reihenfolge von Ziffern, mit der man sich per Telefon mit einer anderen Person verbinden lassen kann) und deshalb fragt, was dieses Wort bedeutet.</strike>

Comment: Der letzte Absatz stimmt, mMn, nur bei der Frage "Was ist _eine_ Telefonnummer?"

Comment: @Iris Ja, stimmt, Sie haben Recht.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard "*Was ist deine Telefonnummer?*" even from native German speakers. It is certainly understood, though probably the sentence with *wie* is more correct.

I believe the choice between *wie/was* is ultimately due to how "complicated" the objects are that are asked for or how many choices there are to pick from. For instance you'd ask:

> Wie ist deine Telefonnummer?
>
> Wie ist deine Anschrift?

since there exist infinitely many (or at least very many) phone numbers and addresses. Now imagine a situation where you have a list of say 20 phone numbers in front of you. In that case you would not use *wie* but ask "Was/Welche ist deine Telefonnummer?", because there is a limited choice of phone numbers to chose from.

Also you'd ask:

> Was ist deine Lieblingsfarbe?

because here you expect an answer out of only about 10 or so options.

Answer (score 2):

Ich schließe mich definitiv meinen Vorrednern in dem Punkt an, dass *wie* und *was* in diesem Fall keinesfalls gleiche Bedeutungen haben.

Ich habe festgestellt, dass zumindest in der Umgangssprache Fragen mit *wie* und *was* ein grundlegender inhaltlicher Unterschied zugrunde liegen.

**Fragen mit wie** gehen davon aus, dass es nur **ein Objekt** dieser Art gibt. Man möchte eher eine Eigenschaft über das Objekt erfahren. Wenn man also nach einer Telefonnummer fragt, meint man damit eine Nummer und möchte quasi nur deren Zahlen erfahren, also eine *Eigenschaft*.

**Fragen mit was** werden meistens eher gebraucht, wenn es darum geht aus **einer möglichen Auswahl ein Objekt** auszuwählen. Also der Fragende ist sich bewusst, dass es verschiedene Möglichkeiten gibt.

---

Das sind mit Sicherheit keine allgültigen Weisheiten, aber definitiv sehr gute Richtlinien. Beispiele, die meine Thesen belegen sind etwa:

> *Was* ist dein Lieblingsauto?

Auswahl aus mehreren Autos, daher: *was*

> *Wie* ist dein Lieblingsauto? (ugs.)

Man weiß, was das Lieblingsauto des Gegenübers ist und möchte nur eine Beschreibung dessen.

> Wie sieht dein Hund aus?

Erwartet wird hier ebenfalls eine Beschreibung, etwa "Braun und klein", und keine Auswahl von Hunderassen, die der Gesprächspartner besonders toll findet.

Comment: I basically agree with your observation (see. my answer to this question),  but I think your examples with *wie* are badly chosen because they ask for a description in the same way as "how" in English.